# Is angular-cli good for beginners

Tags: angular-cli

I'm new in angular and I intended to learn it from scratch. I got this [link](https://angular.io/guide/quickstart). But this site has shown sample angular app build up using angular-cli and it has all inbuilt files and folder structures including testing environment. This wont help a beginner in angular to learn it completely. Please help me to find a better way to learn angular from scratch.

Comment: With frameworks such as Angular, "learn it completely" does not necessarily mean learning every little configuration bit. Consider learning how Angular works and how to build apps with it. After you get more experience, you can learn more about the configuration. For now, use the Angular CLI. Let it build the basic configuration pieces, and build the code for your requirements from there.

Comment: Also, **free** in February, you can take the "Angular: Getting Started" course on Pluralsight here: https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/angular-2-getting-started-update

Answer (score 0):

The official doc is actually really complete and usefull to learn the framework, i'm not sure to understand your problem actually. After 5 min of research [link to tutorial Angular7](https://coursetro.com/posts/code/171/Angular-7-Tutorial---Learn-Angular-7-by-Example).

Hoping it can help you.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to go to Angular’s official website.
[Angular Docs](https://angular.io/)

First Try to understand the advantages of Angular and then the structure and Components of Angular. If you do not understand just by reading then go to this YouTube Playlist.

[Angular 7 Tutorial - YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLC3y8-rFHvwhBRAgFinJR8KHIrCdTkZcZ)

After understanding all the concepts of Angular 7 go to official website and try the “Heroes” project listed there. After completing it you will get a hands on experience on how to Code in Angular 7.
Best of luck for you learning with Angular:)